# How to zip folder that contains more than 12GB data

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to zip a folder which contains large number of files. 
When I tried to zip in command line, it is showing zip error: Input file read failure

I searched net and found "The .ZIP file format, only handles file lengths that can be
contained in a 32-bit integer." If so, then it must be the cause of the error I got, because my folder size is more than 12GB. Is there any way to extend the file size to be zipped.
Or is there another way to solve this?

I am using CENTOS 5.

Thanks.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you zipping it?

Comment: I have to give the admin the option to download the entire folder in a archive form so that he can store the data as backup

Comment: May I ask what the connection is between "32-bit" and "12 GB" here?

Answer (score 19):

You can use tar for that.

Just try:

```
$tar -cvzf compress.tgz /path/to/your/data
```

and to extract it:

```
$tar -xvzf compress.tgz
```

Answer (score 4):

GZip can handle any size that your file system can handle. You might want to first "tar" the content to one file, unsing the GnuTar you can use the z option to do the compression in one go.

7Zip is also a good alternative to ZIP. It is ported to many platforms and the size limits are much higher.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Is there any way to extend the file size to be zipped?

Comment: You should note that you can reasonably expect a compression program to compress no faster than 5-20MB/s, so for compressing 12GB, you have to plan in anywhere from 15 minutes to an hour. If you have to transmit the file over network, that may still be a gain, but otherwise, silen't suggestion to just use tar might be equally good.

Comment: Silent is using "-z" that is only in gnu tar compiled with the gzip libraries. You might not find it in all versions of tar.